# How to assign array of object to dropdown in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I have one html form with several drop downs. I am making api calls to fill data to drop down. Instead of making separate call in one call i am getting all data required to bind all drop downs.
Below is my sample data.

```
{"status":"Success","msg":"Success","code":"200","data":{"Education":[{"ID":1,"Education":"btech"},{"ID":2,"Education":"Bcom"},{"ID":3,"Education":"BA"},{"ID":6,"Education":"PU"}],"MaritalStatus":[{"ID":1,"MaritalStatus":"sinle"},{"ID":2,"MaritalStatus":"married"}]}
```

I am trying to bind it to drop down as below.

```
var martialstatus = new Array();
    var Education = new Array();
    $http.get(baseurl + 'api' + '/Customer/' + 'PersonalInfoMasters').success(function (data) {
        $.map(data.data, function (item) {
            Education.push(item[0]);
        });
        console.log(Education);
    }).error(function (status) {
    });
```

Abobe piece of code gets me first item from the each object like first item from education,martial status etc. I would like to bind education object to education array. May i know where i am missing any line of code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$.map(data.data.Education ` Use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to do any kind of mapping from the original result, so the following would suffice:

```
Education = data.data.Education;
```

Note:

1. The `item[0]` looks strange - are you trying to achieve something with that ?
2. I would use lowercase for the name of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
var martialstatus = new Array();
var Education = [];
$http.get(baseurl + 'api' + '/Customer/' + 'PersonalInfoMasters').success(function(data) {
  $.map(data.data.Education, function(item) {
      Education.push(item);
  });

}).error(function(status) {
});
```

You just need to push `item` instead of `item[0]` in the `.map()` method so it takes the whole `Education` object and push it in your array.

Otherwise you can just use with no need to use the `$.map()`:

```
Education = data.data.Education
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var MaritalStatus = new Array();
var Education = new Array();

$http.get(baseurl + 'api' + '/Customer/' + 'PersonalInfoMasters').success(function (data) {

    $.map(data.data.Education, function (item) {
        Education.push(item);
    });

    $.map(data.data.MaritalStatus, function (item) {
        MaritalStatus.push(item);
    });

}).error(function (error) {

    // handle API errors

});
```

If you do not even need to format the output, you can simply re-assign the original value of your variable.

```
$http.get(baseurl + 'api' + '/Customer/' + 'PersonalInfoMasters').success(function (data) {

    Education = data.data.Education;
    MaritalStatus = data.data.MaritalStatus;

}).error(function (error) {

    // handle API errors

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be more like:

```
$.map(data.data.Education, function (item) {
        Education.push(item[0]);
    });
```

?